# Uncaught ReflectionException in PHP(How to solve it)

Tags: php, reflection, php-7

While trying to learn how to use the PHP ReflectionClass, I run into this problem 
**Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class \DatabaseTable does not exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php(5): ReflectionClass->__construct('\DatabaseTable') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\img\index.php on line 5**.

Meanwhile (just for testing purposes),  index.php, classInfo.php and DatabaseTable.php are all in the same folder.

This is the index.php file

```
<?php
require 'classInfo.php';
require 'DatabaseTable.php';

$class = new ReflectionClass('\\DatabaseTable');

echo classInfo::getData($class);
?>
```

The classInfo.php class has just a single method and it is static.

Comment: Let's see the content of `DatabaseTable.php`

Comment: You sure `\` is the namespace `DatabaseTable` is in?

Comment: It was namepace issue that causes the error. In the b eginning I thought of making testing purpose like an acting project but later decided against it but in the DatabaseTable, I had already namespaced it

Answer (score 0):

Error message says: Class \DatabaseTable does not exist. Are you sure that class defined in DatabaseTable.php?

> Since PHP 5.5, the class keyword is also used for class name resolution. You can get a string containing the fully qualified name of the ClassName class by using ClassName::class

Try to check if class exists:

```
var_dump(class_exists(DatabaseTable::class));
```

Imagine that in DatabaseTable.php:

```
class DatabaseTable
{
    public function __construct() {}
}
```

Then in your index you can write:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass(DatabaseTable::class);
```

**Update**

With namespaces.

```
# DatabaseTable.php

namespace MyNamesapce;

class DatabaseTable
{
    // ...
}

# index.php

use MyNamesapce\DatabaseTable;

$class = new ReflectionClass(DatabaseTable::class);

# or

$class = new ReflectionClass(MyNamespace\DatabaseTable::class);
```

Comment: Thanks..I added namespace before. Is now working after removing it

Comment: If you want, you can use namespace to: `\YourNamesapce\DatabaseTable::class`